# Simulating benchmarks in gem5 Full-System mode using the Arm ISA

Tags: gem5

I am trying to get acquainted with gem5 by running some simple benchmarks.

Following the Arm RSK (https://github.com/arm-university/arm-gem5-rsk) I managed to boot the Linux kernel, and am now trying to run pre-compiled benchmarks included in the disk-image I built. I am running the benchmarks using the `--script` option of the `starter_fs.py` script provided in the RSK.
When trying to simulate benchmarks from the LMbench suite (lat_fifo, lat_mem_rd, lat_fs, lat_fcntl), the program appears to start (console shows appropriate prints), but never seems to terminate (ran for upwards of 24 hours). When I run the benchmarks on my system they execute in seconds.

I also tried running PARSEC benchmarks as described in the RSK. I compiled the canneal package and attempted to run it. This did seem to terminate, but no output was printed to the console or to the log file. I  also encountered unimplemented instruction warnings:

```
warn:   instruction 'unallocated_hint' unimplemented
warn:   instruction 'pacia' unimplemented
```

I tried running using the HPI, Minor, and Atomic CPU models - none seemed to work.
My questions are:

1. Why are the instructions unimplemented, and what can I do to get around the issue?
2. What may be causing the benchmarks to get stuck?
3. In general, what should I do to be able to run benchmarks?

Thanks in advance, any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I don't think the unimplemented instructions are the root of the problem as we always get loads of those on working runs. Hints are ARM instructions with microarchitectural only effects and could be implemented a NOP, so likely not a problem. PACIA I'm not sure with it's getting run, as it should in theory be behind a feature check bit that is only enabled if the feature is implemented.

Comment: Here's [another setup you could try](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/4f82f79be7b0717c12924f4c9b7c4f46f8f18e2f#gem5-buildroot-setup) see also [this section](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#parsec-benchmark).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am trying to follow your guide, but running into issues when trying to run ./build. I tried `./build --download-dependencies gem5-buildroot --arch aarch64`, and am failing on the include of `errno.h` in `lkmc.h` - it says "no such file or directory". Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks
@CiroSantilli

Comment: can you open a ticket on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/issues) giving a little more detail: the g++ compilation command + error message that failed? I'll fix this ASAP.

Comment: Thanks, I took your fix and it seems to solve the problem. 
I am now getting: `make: Makefile.aarch64: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile.aarch64'. Stop.`. Any idea about what may be causing this? @CiroSantilli

Comment: OK, let's try again: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/issues/128 :-)

Comment: Now `./build`` appears to complete, but `./run --emulator gem5 --arch aarch64 fails with `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/linux-kernel-module-cheat/out/gem5/default/build/ARM/gem5.opt'. 
Do you prefer I open an issue for each of these? I am not sure if the problem is with something I'm doing or with the script.@CiroSantilli

Comment: no problem, comments here are fine, I can open a quick issue myself to share with others. Although I use it daily, I hadn't done a full rebuild in a while, but hopefully I can quickly fix any problems :-). Can you double check that the gem5 build finished correctly? You could run `./build-gem5 --arch aarch64` which does just that.

Comment: Thanks, I see it raises an error now:
H5Cpp.h: No such file or directory.
It is included from linux-kernel-module-cheat/out/gem5/default/build/ARM/python/pybind11/stats.cc.
Last command shown is:
[CXX] ARM/sim/power/mathexpr_powermodel.cc -> .o

Comment: OK, yes this is something linked to the libhdf5 that gem5 uses. Can you try `sudo apt install libhdf5-dev` and then rebuild/re-run? I'lll try to add that as a `./build` dependency as well.

Comment: Thanks, that allowed me to complete the build and run successfully. Strangely, though, when I try to build again (tried to make a small change to `hello.c` in `userland` to see how to play around with stuff) I get a new failure:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './linux-kernel-module-cheat/submodules/qemu/configure'`
I am still running gem5 and not QEMU, by the way. @CiroSantilli

Comment: OK, great! Hmmm, what's the exact command? From the error, it looks like the system is trying to build QEMU, but the submodule `submodules/qemu` is not checked out (which is the default, unless you `./build --download-dependencies` for QEMU. So likely you are trying `./build --arch aarch64` instead of `./build --arch aarch64 gem5-buildroot`? But even better, you likely want the more minimal `./build-userland --arch aarch64` and for full system follow with `./build-buildroot --arch aarch64` to add to the image.

Comment: You're right, the mistake was mine. I still can't get use `./build-userland --arch aarch64`, though. It fails with `Error: unknown mnemonic 'incq'` and `Error: unknown mnemonic 'lock'` encountered when compiling x86_64_lock_inc.c. I also tried using `./build-buildroot --arch aarch64` to add a pre-compiled file I made to the image without using `./build-userland` by adding it the .`./out` directory, but I couldn't find the file when I run using the gem5-shell. Which directories are added to the image? Thanks for all your guidance! @CiroSantilli

Comment: I fixed the `unknown mnemonic` thing BTW: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/commit/bbfa782736dfda014dd9b45f26315e0c666443e2 Sorry for those bugs. now I'm trying to get everything working in Docker again :-) To copy  a file into image, the easiest way is to drop it into `rootfs_overlay` and then `./build-buildroot`. I also highly recommend also building QEMU to test stuff out (e.g. is the file in the image), as it boots way faster.